# How to route through a path and perform different functionality at different URLs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I would like to post at the path `/users` and then immediately post to `/users/:id`, but the actions need to be different at each of these URLs, so I can't use the array method for applying the same middleware to different URLs

The idea is that `POST(/users/:id, ...)` will never be called by the client. It only gets called immediately after `POST(/users, ...)`

Comment: If the client is not supposed to send POST requests to `/users/:id`, why add the route in the first place? Just do whatever you need to do inside the handling of `/users`

Comment: Probably another backend service? :) But yeah, it's a bit weird

Comment: I'll give you some background: this is for a learning project with a spec that I don't fully understand because I'm very new to this. I need to explicitly post something to /users, then later, I need to GET /users/:id, but I have no idea how to get /users/:id if I've never posted it in the first place. The testing client never explicitly calls POST /users/:id, so I'm quite lost.

Comment: I guess they want you to write a) `app.post('/users/', ...);` code that adds a new user based on POST data that might include the ID (if not, just use a consecutive number or something) and b) `app.get('/users/:id', ...);` code that retrieves a user based on the ID.

Comment: I think you should read express' documentation about GET and POST, and what's their difference. I've updated my answer, but I don't fully understand your question, as we don't see the testing client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from the comments, you'll need a POST request on `/users` (to persist data in some database) and GET `/users/:id` to retrieve these data, which is very different from POSTing the same thing on 2 different endpoints.

POST is generally used to persist and GET to retrieve data.

I'll assume you use some kind of NoSQL DB, perhaps MongoDB. MongoDB generate a unique ID for each document you persist in it.

So you'll have to have 2 routes :

```
const postUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // persist your user here, perhaps with mongoose or native mongo driver
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }
}

const getUserById = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // get your user here thanks to the id, in req.params.id
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }
}

export default (router) => {
  router.route('/users').post(postUser);
  router.route('/users/:id').get(getUserById);
};
```

Comment: Just for clarification, why don't I need to explicitly call `POST('/users/:id')` before I can GET from that URL?

Comment: Because when you POST your user, you don't know what ID it will have (the database generates it for you). If your user has, let's say, a name and email in your POST request, after you persist it in database it will also have a `_id` field. And that's this ID you use to retrieve it with a GET route thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

When using `express`, you are providing a `handler` function for a specific endpoint. Actually it's an array of those functions (middlewares). That means that you can switch from :

```js
route.post('/users/`, (req, res, next) => {
  // do your magic
});
```

to

```js
route.post('/users/', handleMyCall);
```

This way you can easily reuse those functions in multiple endpoints **without** your need to actually make requests:

```js
route.post('/users/', (req, res) => {
  // do something +
  handleMyCall(req, res);
  // either return the result of this call, or another result
});

route.post('/users/:userID', (req, res) => {
  // do another operation +
  handleMyCall(req, res);
});
```

---

Update:

Using GET or POST differs in the way the data is sent to the server. You can use both for your cases, and it really depends on the testing client you have.

Typically, a GET request is done to query the database and not do any actions. POST is usually used to *create* new entities in the database.

In your scenario, I'd guess you would have `post('/users/`) in order to **create** a user. And then have `get('/users/:userID')` to find that user and return it to the client.

You can easily have different endpoints with different handles for those cases.

Comment: While this is of course true, I don't think it's an answer to OPs problem, given their comment about the spec. It doesn't sound like they are supposed to have a `route.post('/users/:userID'` in the first place.

Comment: Ah, now with this context in mind, I agree I might've perceived the question differently.